# Normal soluble field towers

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

(All fields below are subfields of the field  $\mathbb{C}$).

I am looking for a proof (or disproof) of the following statement:

Let $L:K$ be a normal extension and $K = N_{0} \subset N_{1} \subset N_{2} \ldots \subset N_{n} = L$,        ($n \geq 1$)

be a normal soluble tower, that is  $N_{i} : N_{i-1}$ is normal and $Gal(N_{i} : N_{i-1})$ is soluble, $i=1,2, \ldots, n$.

Then $Gal(L:K)$ is soluble.

A proof sketch. By induction on $n$.

If $n = 1$ then $K = N_{0}$ and $L=N_{1}$. But it is given that $N_{1} : N_{0}$ is soluble.

If $n > 1$ then consider the last 3 fields of the tower. That is,

$N_{n-2} \subset N_{n-1} \subset N_{n} = L$.

The extension $L:N_{n-2}$ is normal (because $L:K$ is normal and $N_{n-2}$ is an intermediate field).

By Galois correspondence, $Gal(N_{n-1}:N_{n-2}) \cong Gal(L:N_{n-2})/Gal(L:N_{n-1})$.

Therefore, $Gal(L:N_{n-2})$ is soluble. (The theorem "If H and G/H are soluble, then G is soluble" was used).

Then $K = N_{0} \subset N_{1} \subset N_{2} \ldots  N_{n-2} \subset N_{n} = L$  is a normal soluble tower of a lesser length.

By induction, $Gal(L:K)$ is soluble.

Any references to the literature are welcome.

Comment: What part of your proof are you not sure about?

Comment: Actually, I am looking for a reference in the literature about using this theorem.